Pipe Symbol in terminal ubuntu via vmware
I can't find how to type the pipe symbol on my VMware. I'm on a Mac m3 pro 14inch. It would be appreciated if someone can help me.

Does this article answer your question?

no doesn't work

What have you tried?   And please edit your question adding in what you have tried so that we are not duplicating information that you have already tried.  As far as I know, you press "shift" and "" keys together to produce the | symbol.

hold/typeCTRL+SHIFT+u, release, type 7c, hit enter -> the general way to type characters with a given code point.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
